# Removing these darn NULLS

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I have an issue that would seem straight forward but for some reason I cannot get rid of my null values from the blow select. All I need this to do is return one row, that one without the NULL value. Can someone please point out the error in my ways? :)

**The result that I get when running:**

```
EffectiveDate            Refund
2015-05-18 00:00:00.000  NULL
2015-05-18 00:00:00.000   1
```

**What I expect back:**

```
EffectiveDate            Refund
2015-05-18 00:00:00.000   1
```

My query:

```
select md.EffectiveDate,
       CASE 
         WHEN 
           ISNULL(ConfigID,'') = 3 THEN '1'
         WHEN 
           ISNULL(ConfigID,'') = 4 THEN '2' 
       END AS Refund
from dbo.PartnerBankConfig md
where md.PartnerID= 100000509
and md.EffectiveDate = (select max(EffectiveDate)
                        from dbo.PartnerBankConfig
                        where PartnerID = 100000509
                        and ISNULL(ConfigID,'') IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Well if you use ISNULL to convert the Nulls to a blank string then IS NOT NULL will never evaluate to True...

Comment: @JacobH: it will never evaluate to False

Comment: Replace `and ISNULL(ConfigID,'') IS NOT NULL)` with `and ConfigID IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Right... so it should just be and ConfigID IS NOT NULL

Comment: I tagged this sql-server, because the `dbo` and `isnull()` strongly suggest that.

Comment: `ISNULL(ConfigID,'') = 3` is the same as `ConfigID=3`.  Calling `ISNULL` in this way is actually slightly worse because it damages the database engine's ability to sarge.

Answer (score 3):

**You get this null because the data doesn't match any condition in your case statement.**  In other words, in that row you have a value for ConfigID that is neither 3 nor 4.  The behavior of a case statement when none of the conditions match is to evaluate to null, and thus null is being returned for this row.

In addition, this function: `ISNULL(ConfigID,'')` replaces any null with an empty string (a non-null value).

Therefore, `ISNULL(ConfigID,'') IS NOT NULL` doesn't make sense.  It is always going to be true, because ISNULL is always returning a non-null value.  You should remove every use of `ISNULL()` from your query, as none of them are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

As Dan explains, your use of `ISNULL()` is just not appropriate.  From your description, you seem to want this simpler query:

```
select md.EffectiveDate,
       (CASE WHEN ConfigID = 3 THEN 1
             WHEN ConfigID = 4 THEN 2
        END) as Refund
from (select md.*, max(EffectiveDate) over (partition by PartnerId) as maxed
      from dbo.PartnerBankConfig md
      where md.PartnerID = 100000509 and
            configId in (3, 4)
     ) md
where md.EffectiveDate = maxed;
```

Or, even more simply:

```
select top (1) with ties md.EffectiveDate,
       (CASE WHEN ConfigID = 3 THEN 1
             WHEN ConfigID = 4 THEN 2
        END) as Refund
from (select md.*, max(EffectiveDate) over (partition by PartnerId) as maxed
      from dbo.PartnerBankConfig md
where md.PartnerID = 100000509 and
      ConfigId in (3, 4)
order by EffectiveDate desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for everyone's feedback this got me going in the right direction I think, Thanks again!